# exam: Change the name of the output PDF file when answers option is enabled

Tags: exam, jobname

If I have a document whose name is `my exam.tex`, is it possible to make its output PDF file have a name of `my exam [solved].pdf` by appending the word `[solved]` **only** when the `answers` class option is enabled?

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\begin{document}
    text
\end{document}
```

Comment: no, you can't change \jobname then. You would have to restart compilation (this needs --shell-escape).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am sorry, but I don't quite understand; do you mean that to make this work I have to compile twice with `--shell-escape`? If yes, I would be grateful if you could provide an answer to show me how to do so.

Comment: You could search for the previous \jobname.pdf and copy it to another filename.  That way they will have different names, even though you can't change the current one.  Frankly, it would be easier just to rename the source file.

Comment: I think @UlrikeFischer means that you could start a new compilation process if `answers` is given as an option. That compilation process could output whatever filename you want, but you can't change the output filename of the current compilation process. (But you could probably run the new process and then end the current one without outputting anything, so you'd only end up with the other-named PDF. Your log file and all the rest would get the current filename, though, and you'd have to run any additional things you need for the new filename (e.g. bibtex/biber/makeindex/another run etc.).

Comment: You can also write a small (shell) script around the compilation that reads the first line of the file and calls LaTeX with the correct jobname depending on whether the first line contains the word `answers` or not. On Linux/Mac you can use `grep` for this, in Windows `findstr`.

Comment: Special case of [compiling - Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files/5265#5265).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution to this problem.

If you compile without `-shell-escape`, it just runs as normal (i.e., if you are using the `answers` option it will output answers, otherwise not; the default `\jobname` is used.)

If you compile with `-shell-escape`, then it outputs two files: `\jobname.pdf` with questions and `\jobname-solved.pdf` with answers. It does this regardless of whether the `answers` option is passed to the class or not.

I've used `latexmk` so that required multiple compilations are taken into account automatically.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{iftex}

\makeatletter

\ltx@IfUndefined{pdf@shellescape}
  {}
  {\ifnum\pdf@shellescape=1
     \ifpdftex
       \def\latexmkengine{-pdf}%
     \fi
     \ifluatex
       \def\latexmkengine{-lualatex}%
     \fi
     \ifxetex
       \def\latexmkengine{-xelatex}%
     \fi
     \pdf@system{%
       latexmk \latexmkengine\space -jobname="\jobname-solved"
         -usepretex="\string\AtBeginDocument{\string\printanswerstrue}"
         "\jobname"
     }%
     \pdf@system{%
       latexmk \latexmkengine\space
         -usepretex="\string\AtBeginDocument{\string\printanswersfalse}"
         "\jobname"
     }%
     \expandafter\stop
   \fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is
  not the same. Which one is different?
  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice John
    \choice Paul
    \choice George
    \choice Ringo
    \CorrectChoice Socrates
  \end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

## Output

### `\jobname.pdf`

[image: output]

### `\jobname-solved.pdf`

[image: output]

---

If you want to only output one file at a time, you can slightly modify the above answer so that `latexmk` is only called when the `answers` option is actually passed to the `exam` class. This answers your question as you've asked it. It still needs to be compiled with `-shell-escape`.

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{iftex}

\makeatletter

\ltx@IfUndefined{pdf@shellescape}
  {}
  {\ifnum\pdf@shellescape=1
     \ifpdftex
       \def\latexmkengine{-pdf}%
     \fi
     \ifluatex
       \def\latexmkengine{-lualatex}%
     \fi
     \ifxetex
       \def\latexmkengine{-xelatex}%
     \fi
     \ifprintanswers
       \pdf@system{%
         latexmk \latexmkengine\space -jobname="\jobname-solved" "\jobname"
       }%
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\stop
     \fi
   \fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is
  not the same. Which one is different?
  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice John
    \choice Paul
    \choice George
    \choice Ringo
    \CorrectChoice Socrates
  \end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

---

And an `expl3` solution that handles file names with spaces. Still needs `-shell-escape` of course.

### Ouptut two files

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_new:N \l__diaa_latexmk_engine_str
\str_new:N \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str
\str_const:Nn \l__diaa_latexmk { latexmk }

\cs_new:Nn \__diaa_build_solved_jobname:
  {
    \str_gset:Nx \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str { \c_sys_jobname_str }
    \str_gremove_all:Nn \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str { " }
    \str_gput_left:Nn \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str { " }
    \str_gput_right:Nn \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str { ~[solved]" }
  }

\sys_if_shell_unrestricted:T
  {
    \sys_if_engine_luatex:T
      { \str_set:Nn \l__diaa_latexmk_engine_str { -lualatex } }
    \sys_if_engine_pdftex:T
      { \str_set:Nn \l__diaa_latexmk_engine_str { -pdf } }
    \sys_if_engine_xetex:T
      { \str_set:Nn \l__diaa_latexmk_engine_str { -xelatex } }
    \__diaa_build_solved_jobname:
    \sys_shell_now:x
      {
        \l__diaa_latexmk \c_space_tl
        \l__diaa_latexmk_engine_str \c_space_tl
        -usepretex="\string\AtBeginDocument{\string\printanswerstrue}" \c_space_tl
        -jobname=\g__diaa_solved_jobname_str \c_space_tl
        \c_sys_jobname_str
      }
    \sys_shell_now:x
      {
        \l__diaa_latexmk \c_space_tl
        \l__diaa_latexmk_engine_str \c_space_tl
        -usepretex="\string\AtBeginDocument{\string\printanswersfalse}" \c_space_tl
        \c_sys_jobname_str
      }
    \stop
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is
  not the same. Which one is different?
  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice John
    \choice Paul
    \choice George
    \choice Ringo
    \CorrectChoice Socrates
  \end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

### Output one file

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_new:N \l__diaa_latexmk_engine_str
\str_new:N \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str
\str_const:Nn \l__diaa_latexmk { latexmk }

\cs_new:Nn \__diaa_build_solved_jobname:
  {
    \str_gset:Nx \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str { \c_sys_jobname_str }
    \str_gremove_all:Nn \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str { " }
    \str_gput_left:Nn \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str { " }
    \str_gput_right:Nn \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str { ~[solved]" }
  }

\sys_if_shell_unrestricted:T
  {
    \sys_if_engine_luatex:T
      { \str_set:Nn \l__diaa_latexmk_engine_str { -lualatex } }
    \sys_if_engine_pdftex:T
      { \str_set:Nn \l__diaa_latexmk_engine_str { -pdf } }
    \sys_if_engine_xetex:T
      { \str_set:Nn \l__diaa_latexmk_engine_str { -xelatex } }
    \legacy_if:nT { printanswers }
      {
        \__diaa_build_solved_jobname:
        \sys_shell_now:x
          {
            \l__diaa_latexmk \c_space_tl
            \l__diaa_latexmk_engine_str \c_space_tl
            -jobname=\g__diaa_solved_jobname_str \c_space_tl
            \c_sys_jobname_str
          }
        \stop
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is
  not the same. Which one is different?
  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice John
    \choice Paul
    \choice George
    \choice Ringo
    \CorrectChoice Socrates
  \end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

---

## Output two files with a call directly to `lualatex` instead of `latexmk`:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_new:N \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str
\str_const:Nn \l__diaa_latex_cmd { lualatex }
\str_const:Nn \l__diaa_latex_options { -synctex=1 ~ -interaction=nonstopmode }

\cs_new:Nn \__diaa_build_solved_jobname:
  {
    \str_gset:Nx \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str { \c_sys_jobname_str }
    \str_gremove_all:Nn \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str { " }
    \str_gput_left:Nn \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str { " }
    \str_gput_right:Nn \g__diaa_solved_jobname_str { ~[solved]" }
  }

\sys_if_shell_unrestricted:T
  {
    \__diaa_build_solved_jobname:
    \sys_shell_now:x
      {
        \l__diaa_latex_cmd \c_space_tl
        -jobname=\g__diaa_solved_jobname_str \c_space_tl
        \l__diaa_latex_options \c_space_tl
        "\string\AtBeginDocument{\string\printanswerstrue}" \c_space_tl
        "\string\input{\c_sys_jobname_str}"
      }
    \sys_shell_now:x
      {
        \l__diaa_latex_cmd \c_space_tl
        -jobname=\c_sys_jobname_str \c_space_tl
        \l__diaa_latex_options \c_space_tl
        "\string\AtBeginDocument{\string\printanswersfalse}" \c_space_tl
        "\string\input{\c_sys_jobname_str}"
      }
    \stop
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is
  not the same. Which one is different?
  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice John
    \choice Paul
    \choice George
    \choice Ringo
    \CorrectChoice Socrates
  \end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks. It works as expected. However, there is one minor flaw; if the file name has spaces such as, for example, `change name.tex` results in this message `Latexmk: Need to specify at most one filename if jobname specified without a %A, but 2 were found (after defaults and wildcarding).`. Moreover, sometimes, I can have more spaces in the file name.

Comment: Another issue, in order to get a space before `[solved]`, I changed the respective line to `-jobname="\jobname\space[solved]"`, did I make it the correct way?

Comment: @Diaa, sigh. File names with spaces are stupid. It can be done, but seems a bit complicated. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93826/how-to-pass-jobname-with-whitespace-to-external-shell-command. But to be honest I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @Diaa, I think I can put together a heavier weight example use `expl3`. I'll update my answer later tonight.

Comment: @Diaa, see bottom example for code that handles file names with spaces.

Comment: Many thanks for your consideration and so sorry for my late reply since I have been out most of the day. I would be highly grateful if you could the case of two outputs at the same time in your last code. My tex knowledge is not good enough to understand how to do it on my own.

Comment: @Diaa, I added the `expl3` option for the case producing two outputs.

Comment: If I would like to use directly `lualatex` instead of running it by `latexmk`, what should be changed in your code? For example, I would like to execute `lualatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode`.

Comment: @Diaa, I added the example of calling `lualatex` directly. It's probably better to ask a new question in cases like this and just reference this question. Someone else might be able to provide an answer more quickly than me as only I see your comment here.

Comment: I appreciate your consideration. I try to minimize the number of asked questions as much as possible :)

Comment: I would be grateful if you could consider looking at [my releveant question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/539020/2288) where I need to add some sort of switch to selectively compile using `latexmk` or `lualatex`.