# How to creating two PDFs on compiling a single .tex file

Tags: pdfpages

I have a .tex file. If I compile it produces a PDF with figures at the last. Now what I want to do is, if I compile it should produce two PDFs, such as one PDF without figures and other with only figures. How can I do? i use Texnic center. The below is my code. If I compile the below code, two PDFs should be created; one without figures (first 5 pages) and other with only figures (last 2 pages!). Please help me how can I do? Thanks.
Raja.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}%Do not change this section
\usepackage{multirow}%Table options
\usepackage{graphicx}%For including figures
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%Headers
\setlength{\headheight}{20mm}%Adjustment for header line in drawing section
\usepackage[top=4.0cm,bottom=3.0cm,left=4.0cm,right=3.0cm]{geometry}%Margin
\usepackage{setspace}%Line spacing
\onehalfspacing%Line spacing of 1.5
%\doublespacing
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
%\linespread{1.4}
\usepackage{lastpage}%Drawing page number starts from 1
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}%Remove 'pagewise' for continous line numbers
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\bfseries\small}%Line number's font
\setlength\linenumbersep{8mm}%Space between line number and text
%\usepackage{showframe}%To show page definition
%\usepackage[grid,gridunit=cm,gridcolor=blue!40,subgridcolor=blue!20]{eso-pic}%Displays page grids
\setlength\parindent{0pt}%No indent in all pages 
\setlength\parskip{2.0ex}%Space between paragraphs
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}%Changing section font/size
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*2}{*0}%Spacing before/after section headings
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\large\bfseries\sffamily BRIEF DESCRIPTION OF DRAWINGS}%List of fig
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0.0mm}%No indent for under section FIGURE 1
%\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{23mm}%Can be replaced for 37, 38 line
\newlength{\mylen}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename\enspace}%Space between FIGURE and its number
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}%Places : next for FIGURE 1
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}%From where the caption starts
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}%moves caption to left, overlaps with FIGURE 1
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@tocrmarg{0mm}%Right margin is set to zero for Drawing section
\makeatother
\usepackage[font=small,labelsep=none]{caption}%Removes : in fig caption below fig
\renewcommand{\figurename}{FIGURE}%Format of FIGURE in 'Description of drawing' section 
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={FIGURE}}%Format of FIGURE below actual figure
\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}%Remove list of figures' page numbers
%\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}%Removes dots

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf {FORM 2\\ THE PATENTS ACT, 1970\\ (Act No.\ 39 of 1970)\\ and\\ THE PATENT RULES, 2003\\
         PROVISIONAL/COMPLETE SPECIFICATION\\
         {[see section 10 and rule 13]}}\\
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}
\end{center}

\section*{APPLICANT(S):}
\begin{tabular}{llp{10cm}}
\multirow{1}{*}{1.}& Name:     & Raj \\
                 & Nationality:& Indian\\
                & Address:    & No.\ 7, Street, Parthasa\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{PREAMBLE TO THE DESCRIPTION}
For complete specification: The following specification particularly describes the invention and the manner in which it is to be performed. (or)\\
For provisional specification: The following specification describes the invention.
\linenumbers
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\pagebreak
\section*{\centering COMPLETE SPECIFICATION}

\section*{TITLE:\\DEVICE FOR WRITING PATENT APPLICATIONS FOR INDIAN PATENTING FROM INDIA AT CHENNAI}

\section*{FIELD OF INVENTION}
Those this is the field of the invention regarding the patent. We wish to apply or a patent in India Herewith, attaching all the documents for your reference. This a simple field that all can understand. Hence, it will be easy for the examiner to report.

Those this is the field o the invention Fig.~\ref{fig:mono} regarding the patent. We wish to apply or a patent in India Herewith, attaching all the documents for your reference. This a simple field that all can understand. Hence, it will be easy for the examiner to report.

\section*{OBJECT OF INVENTION}
Thosethis is the field o the invention as shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:gra} regarding the patent. We wish to apply or a patent in India Herewith, attaching all the documents for your reference. This a simple field that all can understand. Hence, it will be easy for the examiner to report.

Thosethis is the field of the invention regarding the patent. We wish to apply or a patent in India Herewith, attaching all the documents for your reference. This a simple field that all can understand. Hence, it will be easy for the examiner to report.

\listoffigures%comment this section if there is no drawing 

\section*{DETAILED DESCRIPTION}
Those this is the field o the invention as shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:gra} regarding the patent. We wish to apply or a patent in India Herewith, attaching all the documents for your reference. This a simple field that all can understand. Hence, it will be easy for the examiner to report.
\clearpage
\section*{CLAIMS}
I/We claim:
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{claim:independent1} I am/We are in possession of the above-mentioned invention.
\item The provisional/complete specification as in~\ref{claim:independent1} relating to the invention is filed with this application.
\item The invention as disclosed in the specification uses the biological material from India and the necessary permission from the competent authority shall be submitted by me/us before the grant of patent to me/us.
\item There is no lawful ground of objection(s) to the grant of the patent to me/us
\item I am/We are the true and first inventor(s).
\item I am/We are the assignee or legal representative of true and first inventor(s).
\item The application or each of the applications, particulars of which are given in paragraph-8, was the first application in convention country/countries in respect of my/our invention(s).
\item I/We claim the priority from the above mentioned application(s) filed in convention country/countries and state that no application for protection in respect of the invention had been made in a convention country before that date by me/us or by any person from which I/we derive the title.
\item My/Our application in India is based on international application under Patent Cooperation Treat (PCT) as mentioned in paragraph-9.
\item The application is divided out of my/our application particulars of which is given is paragraph-10 and pray that this application may be treated as deemed to have been filed on 13.09.2020 under section 16 of the Act.
\item The said invention is an improvement in or modification of the invention particulars of which are given paragraph-11.
\end{enumerate}
\clearpage
\section*{ABSTRACT}
This is the abstract of the invention. It should be only within 150 words. Usually no big abstracts are allowed. Also I have no idea why abstracts are often comes at the end of the patent application. So I too follow the same order in Indian patenting system. The application or each of the applications, particulars of which are given in paragraph-8, was the first application in convention country/countries in respect of my/our invention(s). This is the abstract of the patent. It should be only within 150 words. Usually no big abstracts are allowed. Also I have no idea why abstracts are often comes at the end of the patent application. So I too follow the same order in Indian patenting system. The application or each of the applications, particulars of which are given in paragraph-8, was the first application in convention country/countries in respect of my/our invention(s).

\textbf{Dated this \textbf{xxth} day of \textbf{September, 2020}\\\\\\\\
Signature:\\
Name: S.~Rajagopalan}
\pagebreak
\section*{DRAWINGS}

\setcounter{page}{1}%drawings page starts from 1
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%Applicant no. and names on top left side of drawing sheet%
\fancyhead[L]{\textbf{Applicant name(s): 1.\,Rajagopalan, 2.\,Uma,\\ 3.\,Sanvika\\Application no.: 123456599}}
%Drawing sheet numbering at top right side of drawing sheets%
\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{Sheet no.: \thepage \\Total no.\ of sheets: \pageref{LastPage}}}
%Bottom right for signing by patent agent or applicant%
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{Signature\\S. Rajn\\IN/PA xx}}
%Including all your figures as per Latex %

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=110mm]{monomer2}
\caption[This is the figure caption for the above figure. It displays usefulness of many quantities for the present data evolution of the fact.]{}\label{fig:mono}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=110mm]{sam3}
\caption[The above figure is very simple graph from a pdf which is may be relevant for the present work.]{}\label{fig:gra}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A single execution of pdflatex (or xelatex/lualatex) will never create more than one PDF. The subfiles package would allow you to compile one part or the other or separately or together as you chose. Or you can write a script that compiles the PDF and then splits it into two PDFs using pdfjam or similar tool like qpdf or pdftk or even ghostscript. But if you want more detailed instructions on that, it would help (for me at least) to know what operating system you're using, and exactly how you want page numbers to be handled.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423109/export-each-figure-as-a-separate-pdf-file/423253?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C43.3744#423253

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Operating system: Windows 8.1 pro; 64 bit (no license). If you compile the code, you will get a single PDF with page numbers, except the drawing page, i.e. the last 2 pages. I just want to split the drawing page alone as one pdf and the rest as another pdf.

Comment: The easiest is to open the PDF, choose Print, select the pages you want, then "print to file" or something similar (it can be called differently depending on the PDF viewer that you use).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521824/87678